# How to mask a url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, custom-wordpress-pages, url-masking, domain-masking

Is it possible to mask a **url** to a new domain in **wordpress**?
For example: URL : *abc.com/test*
I want the content of *abc.com/test* but the *url* to be changed to *xyz.com*.
I have tried adding **.htaccess** code but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can 301 redirect from `abc.com/test` to `xyz.com` but the wordpress deployment should be running on `xyz.com`

```
RewriteEngineOn
RewriteCond%{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com/test RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [P]
```

add this to the `.htaccess` file on `abc.com/test` path